# problem in jQuery popup and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax.net

i am having problem when i do the ajax call then my popup stop working.
i want to call ajax when we click on "ok" button of popup.
thanks in advance

here is my code:

---

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='content'>
        <div id='confirm-dialog'>
       <asp:Button ID="cmdBackToHomePageTop" runat="server" Text="<<  Back to Home Page" Width="160px" OnClick="cmdBackToHomePageTop_Click"/>

        </div>

        <!-- modal content -->
        <div id='confirm'>
            <div class='header'><span>Test Conformation Title</span></div>
            <div class='message'></div>
            <div class='buttons'>
                <div class='no simplemodal-close'>Cancle</div><div id='ok' class='yes'>Ok</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

### jQuery file

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $('[id$=button],[id$=cmdBackToHomePageTop]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // example of calling the confirm function
        // you must use a callback function to perform the "yes" action
        confirm("hello friends?", function () { 


            $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "./default2.aspx/cmdbacktohomepagetop_click"
                   )};      
        });
    });
});

function confirm(message, callback) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
        //closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
        position: ["20%",],
        overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
        containerId: 'confirm-container', 
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            $('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);

            // if the user clicks "yes"
            $('#ok', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
                // call the callback

                if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback.apply();       
                }
                // close the dialog
                $.modal.close();           

            });
        }
    });
}
```

### codebhind:

```
protected void cmdBackToHomePageTop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("called --- cmdBackToHomePageTop_Click");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not capturing the response from the Ajax call.  It looks like you're already doing one callback (when the user clicks OK in the confirmation) but you still need to add another to the Ajax request itself. Otherwise, the request is happening just fine, you're just not doing anything with the results.

Usually, you will want to supply your callback function to this via the `success`, `error`, and/or `complete` properties of $.ajax(...);

For example,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "./default2.aspx/cmdbacktohomepagetop_click",
    data: 'xml',
    success: mySuccessHandler,
    error: function() {alert('Bummer, an error occurred')}
)};
function mySuccessHandler(data) {
    // process the response!
}
```

You can refer to [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more documentation and examples. Especially for more information on the parameters that will end up getting passed into your various callbacks. The example I gave is just to show some possibilities.

best of luck!

Comment: p.s., you may also want to consider keeping the modal open until the ajax has returned. Or to have some kind of 'please wait' message while the request is in progress. Right now, it looks like the modal will close instantly when your user clicks OK, which might be confusing if the request takes more than a few seconds.